# AWS SES receipt rules for something@example.com not being triggered as expected

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, email, dns, cloudflare

EDIT:  My client has returned with an error message (2 day timeout) `Delivery attempt history for your mail:

```
Sun, 02 Sep 2018 21:20:35 +0000 (GMT)
TCP active open: Failed connect() to TCP port 25 of 104.27.139.56 104.27.138.56 last    Error: Connection timed out`
```

The IP it mentions is Cloudflare, I've posted in their forum but thought worth asking as i do think this is the problem I'm experiencing and perhaps need to remove Cloudflare altogether

My scenario is:

- SES is no longer in sandbox mode.
- I've verified my domain and my personal email address.
- I've added the `TXT` / Name records to cloudflare (I'm wondering if they are the issue)
- I've set up rules such that 'something@example.com' and 'anything@example.com' should trigger by sending the email to an S3 bucket.

S3 isn't my ideal solution but as a proof of concept it'll do.

However, emails sent to 'something@example.com' are not getting through, nothing is in S3 and I'm receiving (via my personal email) a

```
Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
3 hours ago at 12:58 PM
From
MAILER-DAEMON@amazonses.com
To  
myemail@me.com

An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
something@example.com
```

Can anyone perhaps shed some light on what I may be doing wrong?

MX records (in Cloudflare) have been updated to these that I obtained from SES:
amazonses - 10 feedback-smtp.us-east-1.amazonses.com - proxy is automatic

Comment: You didn't show the actual error from the non-delivery report... but you also didn't mention configuring MX records.  Did you?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - That block for the delivery status notification is the only error I've received so far (unless they're being filtered off into spam).  MX records have been updated - I'll edit the question to show info.  Thanks!

Comment: `feedback-smtp` is not the correct MX for *receiving* mail, so you either have a misconfiguration there, or your question doesn't describe what you're actually trying to do... the MX record begins with `inbound-smtp`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - ah, thankyou - I was not aware of that.  All of the guides etc I had come across pointed to created a 'Rule Set' within SES for that Domain name and that it would be handled.
I've since added in the api/smtp endpoints to cloudflare and have sent another email to my domain, nothing showing as yet though, possibly taking some time to update the records or maybe there's something else I'm missing.